# Numpy vectorized implementation of term-by-term division in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have one matrix and one vector, of dimensions (N, d) and (N,) respectively. For each row, I want to divide each element by the corresponding value in the vector. I was wondering if there was a vectorized implementation (to save computation time). (I'm trying to create points on the surface of a d-dimensional sphere.) Right now I'm doing this:

```
x = np.random.randn(N,d) 
norm = np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1)

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(d):
        x[i][j] = x[i][j] / norm[i]
```

Comment: Make `norm` a (N,1) array.  the `x/norm` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.linalg.norm` has a `keepdims` argument just for this:

```
x /= np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```